# Python: how to create dictionary from lists with only certain values using a for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary

I am a newbie Python user. I have two dictionaries (A and B). Each dictionary has coordinate info, which means I have four lists of coordinates (latA, longA, latB, longB). I'm trying to measure the distance between each event in coordinate list 1, which comes from dictionary A, relative to every single event in list 2 (dict B). Then I'd like to create a new dictionary, C, that includes only those events that are close to each other (less than 1km, etc) and that also includes all the other information included in the original dictionaries (A and B).

I am able to calculate all distances and create a list of short distances. Nevertheless, I don't know how to take this list of short distances and create a new dictionary that includes all the values that I need from dictionaries A and B.

## Calculates all possible distances between events in Dict A and events in Dict B

```
C = {}
dist_km=[]

for row in product(zip(latA, longA), zip(latB, longB)):
    e=(list(chain(*row)))
    distance= distance_function(e[0],e[1],e[2],e[3])
    dist_kilo=(distance*6373)
    dist_km.append(dist_kilo)
```

## Creates new dict (if distance is 1 km or less) (this didn't work)

```
    if dist_kilo<1.01: 
        C= dict([("clat", latA)])
        C["clong"]= ("clong", longA)
        C["tlat"]= ("tlat", latB)
        C["tlong"]= ("tlong", longB)
```

My thinking was that Python was going to create a dictionary using the values of only those observations with short distances but this code didn't work. It basically just appended four lists (latA, longA, latB, and longB) regardless of the length of dist_kilo.

Anybody knows how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for row in product(zip(latA, longA), zip(latB, longB)):`

- If i'm reading this right, Row will be a tuple of tuples:

`((latA[i], longA[i]),(latB[i], longB[i]))` ?

So if you want to access the value of those you should be using row[0][0] row[0][1], row[1][0], row[1][1] rather than latA since youre in an iterator.

But also, looking at this, you need to return a LIST of dictionaries right? One list item with the 4 dictionary key value pairs? Something like this?

```
C = {}
dist_km=[]
returned_values=[]

for row in product(zip(latA, longA), zip(latB, longB)):
    e=(list(chain(*row)))
    distance= distance_function(e[0],e[1],e[2],e[3])
    dist_kilo=(distance*6373)
    dist_km.append(dist_kilo)

    if dist_kilo<1.01: 
        C  ={
            "clat":row[0][0],
            "clong": row[0][1],
            "tlat":row[1][0],
            "tlong": row[1][1],
            "distance_km": dist_kilo
        }
        returned_values.append(C)
```

Comment: @ TechnicalChaos, thanks, this worked great, only thing I'm still unclear is how to add "dist_km" to "returned_values"...

Comment: When you build the `C` dictionary with the 4 rows, just add in `'distance_kilometres': dist_kilo`
     C  ={
            "clat":row[0][0],
            "clong": row[0][1],
            "tlat":row[1][0],
            "tlong": row[1][1],
            "distance_km": dist_kilo
        }

Answer (score 0):

The code creates a new dict by `C= dict([("clat", latA)])` for every set of matching coordinates so `C` should have at most four keys: "clat", "clong:, "tlat", "tlong". You already created the dictionary by `C = {}` prior to the `for` loop. To add entries within the `for` loop just do `C[key] = value`

You may want to store the matching cooordinates in a list of tuples: (latA, longA, latB, longB). Or if there is other information you want to associate with each set of matching coordinates, use the matching tuples as keys in a dict.